# multiple JPanels paint image in JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, jlayeredpane

this is my code and when I add JPanel to JLayeredPane  it can not to display any image.
 I dont know how to display multiple jpanel when I need put them on my screen

```
public class game extends JFrame {
        private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
        private GraphicPanel gui;
        private gameWindows test;

           public game(){


            this.setTitle("gameVer0.01");
            this.setUndecorated(true);
            setLocationRelativeTo(this);
             gui=new GraphicPanel("url");
             test=new gameWindows("url");
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());     
        layeredPane =new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));


         layeredPane.add(test, 100);
         layeredPane.add(gui, 200);
         layeredPane.setOpaque(true);
        layeredPane.setVisible(true);
         this.add(layeredPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setResizable(false);
            setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            final GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
            device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
            device.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1280,720,32,60));  
            this.setSize(400,400);
            this.pack();
            this.setVisible(true);


        }
        public  static void main(String srg[]){

                game window=new game();

               new BasicListener(window);

              }

    }
    class gameWindows extends JPanel {
         public gameWindows(String url)
          {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,720));
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setBackground(Color.blue);
            this.setOpaque(false);  
          }
        Image image1,image2;
           public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                /* Call the original implementation of this method */
                super.paintComponent(g);
             try {
                    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\casper\\Desktop\\123\\game test\\src\\data\\res\\background.png");
                    image1 = ImageIO.read(fi);
                    fi.close();
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex) {
                      System.out.println("No example.jpg!!");
                  }
                 g.drawImage(image1, 0,0, null);

                }   

    }
    class GraphicPanel extends JPanel
    {
      public GraphicPanel(String url)
      {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.blue);
        this.setOpaque(false);

      }
      @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          /* Call the original implementation of this method */
          super.paintComponent(g);
         try {
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\casper\\Desktop\\123\\game test\\src\\data\\res\\1.jpg");      
                image = ImageIO.read(fi);
                fi.close();
              }
              catch (Exception ex) {
                  System.out.println("No example.jpg!!");
              }

              g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
      }
     }
```

This question bothers me day

Thanks for all respondents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JLayeredPane uses a null layout. So you are responsible for setting the size and location of any component you add to the layered pane. Otherwise the default size is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for working examples. Download the demo code and test it and make sure you understand it. Then you can fix your code.